# Add Cookie SameSite None to Drupal7 and PHP7.0

Tags: php, cookies, drupal, drupal-7, php-7.0

Is there a good solution to add the Cookie `SameSite None` configuration to a Drupal7 and PHP7.0 setup?

My only finding was to override the file `includes/session.inc` from :

```
setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), $expire, $params['path'], $params['domain'], $params['secure'], $params['httponly']);
```

to

```
header("Set-Cookie: {$cookie_name}={$session_id}; Domain=localhost; Path={$params['path']}; SameSite=None; Secure; HttpOnly; ");
```

It does not even seem to work in all situations...

Comment: With [7.0 being end of life](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php), I think `header()` is your only real option. Can I ask why you're setting the session cookie to `SameSite=None`? Is the site primarily used in a cross-site embedded context?

Comment: Our payment provider is redirecting our customer with a POST request directly to our website.

Comment: I need to do the same in PHP7.2 for my session cookie, sadly don't know where to edit the cookie creation or append the samesite=lax parameter to this particular cookie.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a hack but you can set SameSite to None for the session cookie by adding this to your settings.php :

```
ini_set('session.cookie_path', '/; samesite=None');
```